# Complex Cube Roots - Argand Diagram Question

Tags: complex-numbers

Suppose you have $3$ points on Argand diagram, evenly spread ($\frac{2\pi}{3}$ apart), represented by complex numbers $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$, with moduli $\sqrt{2}$, if we take another complex number on the circle around the other points, call it $\omega$, can you show that:

$|(\omega-\alpha)^2+(\omega-\beta)^2+(\omega-\gamma)^2|=6$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid notation confusion let us call the new point $z = \sqrt{2}e^{i\theta}$, because $\omega$ is reserved for cube root of unity. We know that : $$(1 + \omega + \omega^2) = 0$$ So the points we are talking about are :

$$\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2}\omega, \sqrt{2}\omega^2$$  Let us compute : $$ |(z-\sqrt{2})^2 + (z-\sqrt{2}\omega)^2 + (z-\sqrt{2}\omega^2)^2|$$

$$ = |(\sqrt{2}e^{i\theta}-\sqrt{2})^2 + (\sqrt{2}e^{i\theta}-\sqrt{2}\omega)^2 + (\sqrt{2}e^{i\theta}-\sqrt{2}\omega^2)^2|$$

$$ = 2|(e^{i\theta}-1)^2 + (e^{i\theta}-\omega)^2 + (e^{i\theta}-\omega^2)^2|$$

$$ = 2|3e^{2i\theta} -2e^{i\theta}(1 + \omega + \omega^2) + (1 + \omega + \omega^2)|$$

Note here we use $\omega^3 = 1$ while expanding.

Thus we have :

$$ = 2|3e^{2i\theta}| = 2\times 3 = 6$$

Hence, proved LHS = RHS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just have a few questions. The three points are solutions to $z^3=2+2i$, not $z^3=1$, does this affect anything. You also cancel out the last two terms in the 4th line of computation, how do you know $2e^{i\theta}=1$?

Comment: Oh wait, the sum of roots $=0$, its just the first part I'm not sure about then.

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of generality we can take $\alpha=\sqrt{2}z_0$, $\beta=\sqrt{2}z_0e^{2i\pi\over 3}$ and $\gamma=\sqrt{2}z_0e^{4i\pi\over 3}$. Let $\omega=\sqrt{2}e^{i\Omega}$. We have denoting $j=e^{2i\pi\over 3}$

$$\begin{align}S=(\omega-\alpha)^2+(\omega-\beta)^2+(\omega-\gamma)^2=&2(z_0^2+e^{2i\Omega}-2z_0e^{i\Omega})\\&+2(z_0^2j^2+e^{2i\Omega}-2jz_0e^{i\Omega})\\&+2(z_0^2j^4+e^{2i\Omega}-2j^2z_0e^{i\Omega})\end{align}$$

Keep in mind that $j^3=1$ and $1+j+j^2=0$. The sum rewrites as

$$S=2\cdot [3e^{2i\Omega}+(1+j+j^2)(z_0^2-2z_0e^{i\Omega})]=6\cdot e^{i\Omega}$$

And as requested we have proven $|S|=6$

Comment: As I mentioned above, the points were solutions to $z^3=2+2i$, so the position on the graph is not symmetrical about the $x$-axis and $j^3$ will equal $2+2i$ now won't it?

Comment: The three cubic roots of any complex number are of the form $\{z_0,z_0\cdot j,z_0\cdot j^2\}$ where $j$ is the non real cubic root of $1$and therefore their sum will be $z_0(1+j+j^2)=0$. I will edit my solution.